# NoReverseMatch when adding comments section in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add comments to my blog, but I have this error and I cannot figure out why.

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /2024/01/01/lesson-1/

Reverse for 'post_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/(?P<lesson>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/comment/\\Z']
```

with highlight on:

```
<form action="{% url 'lang_learning_app:post_comment' post.id %}" method="post">
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...    
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:lesson>/', views.lesson_detail, name='lesson_detail'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:lesson>/comment/', views.post_comment, name='post_comment'),
    ...]
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'body']
```

models.py

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.DRAFT)
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-publish']),
        ]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lang_learning_app:lesson_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Lesson,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['created']),
        ]
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.name} on {self.post}'
```

views.py

```
@require_POST
def post_comment(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Lesson, id=post_id, status=Lesson.Status.PUBLISHED)
    comment = None
    # A comment was posted
    form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Create a Comment object without saving it to the database
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        # Assign the post to the comment
        comment.post = post
        # Save the comment to the database
        comment.save()
    return render(request, 'lessons/comment.html', {'post': post, 'form': form, 'comment': comment})
```

comment_form.html

```
<h2>Add a new comment</h2>
<form action="{% url 'lang_learning_app:post_comment' post.id %}" method="post">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
</form>
```

lesson_detail.html

```
{% with comments.count as total_comments %}
<h2>
    {{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}
</h2>
{% endwith %}
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comment">
    <p class="info">
    Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by {{ comment.name }}
    {{ comment.created }}
    </p>
    {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
</div>
{% empty %}
<p>There are no comments yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
{% include "lessons/comment_form.html" %}
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error, I have followed instructions from book Django by example. I have made some adjustments for my blog, instead of post I have used lesson. Do you have any idea why I'm getting this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reverse for 'post_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found` is usually a telltale that a context variable used in the `{% url %}` tag is empty.

Django `{% url %}` tags struggle with the concept of `None` or "optional" arguments. The context variables are resolved *first*, meaning that if the attribute doesn't exist, it renders to a default empty string `''`.

`{% url %}` and the `reverse()` machinery then try to resolve a URL using the empty string. If you think about it, this would create a nonsensical URL, like `app/posts//comments`. There aren't really any hidden assumptions made by Django here; it expects URLs and arguments to match precisely.

What this means for you is that you have to pass *all* the URL parameters that are expected by the `path()` entry, as defined in `urls.py` and/or `urlpatterns`. Instead of:

```
<form action="{% url 'lang_learning_app:post_comment' post.id %}" method="post">
```

You need something like:

```
<form action="{% url 'lang_learning_app:post_comment' post.published.year post.published.month post.published.day post.slug %}" method="post">
```

Now, you may be looking at that and thinking, "that would be dreadful to write in more than one template", and you'd be correct in my opinion. Long, complicated `{% url %}` tags are difficult to maintain. When you run into this, consider resolving the URL in Python using Django's `reverse()` function. It's the same as what `{% url %}` does under the hood, but you have more control over it in Python versus the template.

Comment: That's a much clearer explanation than mine - should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the book you're working through but to me, it looks like a mismatch between the template, the view and the urls code.

I think the view is expecting a request with one parameter to identify the post id.  And the template is trying to send that single id.  But the urls file, which is where django is looking for a pattern to use when it tries to generate the html, doesn't have an entry with a single parameter called `<int:post_id>` so it fails with that error message.

Try tacking that on the end of your post_comment url line in urls.py.
`path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:lesson>/comment/<int:post_id>', views.post_comment, name='post_comment'),`

TBH I don't know how it's going to get all the other parameters it needs as I haven't used this design pattern myself - perhaps django handles all that.

Comment: still it doesn't work, `Reverse for 'post_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/(?P<lesson>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/comment/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']`

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the models.py code for the Lesson object?  You may need to include all the extra variables inside the {url} tag in the template.  As I say, I haven't used this specific pattern myself.

Comment: I mean your template might need to look like: `{% url 'lang_learning_app:post_comment' post.year post.month post.day post.lesson post.id %}`.  So it can satisfy all the arguments for the url lookup.

Comment: when I change url, I got this as an error: `Reverse for 'post_comment' with arguments '('', '', '', '', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/(?P<lesson>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/comment/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']`

Comment: OK, so I was guessing that you Lesson model had year, month, day, and lesson attributes, but it doesn't, so it's using empty strings.  And I don't know where it's getting the brackets from at either end.  Not seen that before.  You can see that you're on the right track here but you'll have to find a way to pass the right parameters to the url tag in the template so it can match the pattern in the urls.py file.  When I get stuck like this, I put some hard coded info (like 2023 12 15 'test' 10) into the url tag to allow it to do a lookup and see which variables are giving me issues.

Comment: Once you can get it to generate the html and display a page, you can add something like this `<!-- {{ post.id|safe }} -->` into your template and then look at the html source in your browser to see what the actual value of that variable is.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I manage to solve by deleting `action="{% url 'lang_learning_app:post_comment' post.id %}"`, it works for now. Appreciate for your help :)